# Submit only first time knockout.js and bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, bootstrap-modal

I have problem, with knockout.js and bootstrap modal. On button click i open bootastrap modal, for creating new city. Then i submit form and save in base. Problem is because submiting works only first time. After that it doesn't work.
Here is how it look like

html file

```
> <!-- Modal add new city
>      ==================================================-->
>     <div class="modal fade" id="addCity" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
>       <div class="modal-dialog">
>         <form data-bind="submit: onSubmit">
>         <div class="modal-content">
>           <div class="modal-header">
>             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
>             <h4 class="modal-title">Dodaj novi grad</h4>
>           </div>
>           <div class="modal-body">
>             <div class="input-group">
>               <span class="input-group-addon">Ime grada</span>
>               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ime grada" data-bind="value : city_name">
>           </div
>     
>     
>         </div>
>           <div class="modal-footer">
>             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Zatvori</button>
>             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sacuvaj</button>
>           </div>
>         </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
>         </form>
>       </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
>     </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

js file

```
    var viewModel = ko.computed(function()
{
    var self = this;

        var cities = getAllCities();
    self.cities = ko.observableArray(cities);



    self.city_name = ko.observable();
    self.logo_path = ko.observable();

    //add new city
    self.onSubmit = function() 
    {

        var data = JSON.stringify(
            {
                city_name : self.city_name(), logo_path : self.logo_path()        
            }); // prepare request data
        var response =  ajaxJsonPost("/services/private_service/add_city", data, false, false);
        if (response.status === ResponseStatus.SUCCESS) {
        $("#cityName").attr("value", "");
        $('#addCity').modal('hide');
        self.cities.push(data);
        } else {
            //handle error
        }
    };

});

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just do an ajax request instead of a form submit? Something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/services/private_service/add_city",
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        $("#cityName").attr("value", "");
        $('#addCity').modal('hide');
        self.cities.push(data);
    }
});
```

Unless you have written script for this method, I'm not familiar with "ajaxJsonPost()".

Comment: Yes, ajaxJsonPost is method which sends JSON to rest service. I think the problem is when i try to hide modal. He is just hidden, and next time when i trigger modal, it is the same modal which i triggered first time. I don't know how to destroy modal after submit, not just to hide him.

Comment: Then after self.cities.push(data) could you not write: self.city_name(null). You don't need to destroy your modal, you just want to clear your observables.

Comment: You are also trying to clear the #city_name element which does not exist in your markup.

Comment: Sorry, I have copied here wrong code, i have already repaired that,  with #new_city_name.  With self.new_city_name, input has reset, but i still have same problem. When i removed $('#addCity').modal('hide'); everything works fine, except modal stays opened.